# Any way to turn off the printer progress bar (silent printing) in Windows (maybe with MS Access)?

Tags: windows, ms-access, printing, vba

I have an MS Access form that checks for certain records in a form timer event.

When it finds records it prints a report to the default Windows printer.

The problem is the Windows print status/progress window pops up (You know, the one that goes Printing page x of (document name)). And it, of course, has a cancel button.

But that progress window is interfering with normal form operations. I want to print in the background (silent printing?) without showing that progress window.

Any way to do that in the printer settings or from vba or other?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's by design.

But you could move this timer form and the report to another database and run this minimized - your current application could open this automatically when launched.

Comment: Interesting. So, if the 2nd database is running minimized, the printing progress window doesn't pop up during printing?

Comment: By second thought, I'm not sure. But it would be very easy for you to check out.